# Changing Report Layout of a pivot table By Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am generating a pivot table using VBA in Excel. By default the Report Layout is `'Outline Form'`. How can I change this to `'Compact form'` or `'Tabular Form'` through my code ? Any help is appreciated ! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By running the Macro Recorder I get this code for changing it to Compact:

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
```

To get it into Tabular Form, sure enough:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
```

Remember, the Macro Recorder is your friend.

Comment: Ahh the Macro Recorder ! Totally skipped my mind to try that. Thank you so much :)